# Is an app req'd for HDMI/Iphone 4 to view photos?

Tags: view, iphone-4, photos, hdmi

Is the Iphone4 with HDMI adapter, a plug and play or is an app required to view photos on TV? Mine is not sending a signal to the TV.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a plug and play.  Check the connections and the cable.

Answer (score 0):

Friend of mine had the same issue. The HDMI cable was bad. Check the HDMI cable with another device to make sure its not faulty... you shouldn't need anything extra to do this with the adapter.